# I am using the Angular "Date" filter, but what is this numerical expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the Angular tutorial there is an example of the `date` filter being used like this:

```
{{ 1304375948024 | date }} -->  May 2, 2011`
```

What is the notation of the expression `1304375948024`?

Comment: It is milliseconds since epoch. it is what [dateObj.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime#Returns) gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is a measure of the number of seconds that have elapsed since the *Unix Epoch*, defined as `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970`

Check out [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) which shows that `1304375948024` represents `Mon, 02 May 2011 22:39:08 GMT`

As pointed out by **@PSL** in a comment - this is the type of value you will receive from the standard javascript [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). Note that in javascript, this value is in **milliseconds** and not seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The number is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. It is a common format among date objects across various languages.